# Button click event is not firing in asp.net gridview control

Tags: c#, gridview, controls

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvInaciveQuestions" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="gvInaciveQuestions_RowCommand">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Selelct">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Button ID="btnactive" runat="server"  Text="Active" onClick="btnactive_Click" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>                   
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Question">
 </asp:Gridview>
```

I have added Itemtemplate as Button but it is not firing `onclick` event.

Could please any one suggest me ?

Answer (score 1):

Don't `DataBind` it on every postback  by using the `Page.IsPostBack` property, for example in `Page_Load`(resuming that the method that you're using for databinding is called `BindGridView`):

```
protected void Page_Load(ovject sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGridView();
    }
}
```

Otherwise events aren't triggered and changed values in the grid are overwritten by the values from your (old) `DataSource`.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use `onClick="btnactive_Click"` event here, instead use `CommandName` property.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnactive" runat="server"  Text="Active" CommandName="Click" />
```

In your `OnRowCommand` in codebehind implement like this.

```
 protected void gvInaciveQuestions_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.CommandName == "Click")
                {
                  //your code here
                }
            }
```

I hope this will solve your issue.

-
Harsha Ch